# Cannot cast from object to int

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors

Even though I have done the exact same thing with an integer array, I seem to be getting an 'Cannot cast from object to int' error while passing the integer from a servlet to a jsp

In my JavaBean

```
public int getNoOfVotes(){
    return noOfVotes;
}
```

In my servlet

```
int noOfVotes = bean.getNoOfVotes();
request.setAttribute("totalVotes", noOfVotes);
```

In my jsp

```
int votes = (int)request.getAttribute("totalVotes");
```

Its in the jsp I am getting the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.getAttribute` returns Object. You cannot cast Object to a primitive type `int`. But you may cast it to `Integer`.

Comment: It is not the problem because autoboxing traduct Integer to int

Comment: Autoboxing was introduced in Java 1.5. Can you imagine how outdated OP's project is.

Comment: Didn't know autoboxing works in such way. Now I know. But I swear I will never use it :-D

Comment: Had to cast the integer to an int to be able to print it out in my JSP but other than that it worked like a charm, thanks a million :) @PavelVlasov

Answer (score 0):

reality，the obj couldn't cast to int,there are two method to cast.
the one is cast to String,then use Integer.valueof();
the other one is Integer.parsetoInt()

Answer (score -2):

Try using this

```
int no = Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("totalVotes"));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: In the future, actually try it yourself before doing off as an answer. Bonus is, you'll actually learn something yourself by real experience :) If you can't answer for sure just post a comment once you've sufficient reputation.